# improve a for loop with apply inside

Tags: r

I have a data.frame, ordered by *mean* column that looks like this:

```
        10SE191_2  10SE207  10SE208     mean
7995783  12.64874 13.06391 12.69378 12.73937
8115327  12.69979 12.52285 12.41582 12.50363
8108370  12.58685 12.87818 12.66021 12.45720
7945680  12.46392 12.26087 11.77040 12.36518
7923547  11.98463 11.96649 12.50666 12.33138
8016718  12.81610 12.71548 12.48164 12.32703
```

I would like to apply a `t.test` to each row, using as input the intensity values: `df[i,1:3]` and the *mean* values from the rows with lower intensities. For example, for the first row I want to compute a t.test for `df[1,1:3]` *vs* _mean values_ from row 2 to row 6.  My code uses a *for loop* but my current data.frame has more than 20,000 rows and 24 columns and it takes a long time. Any ideas for improving the code?

Thanks

Code:

```
temp <- matrix(-9, nrow=dim(matrix.order)[1], ncol=2) #create a result matrix
l <- dim(matrix.order)[1]
for (i in 1:l){
j <- 1+i
if (i < l | j +2 == l) { #avoid not enough y observations
mean.val <- matrix.order[j:l,4]
p <- t.test(matrix.order[i, 1:3], mean.val)
temp[i,1] <- p$p.value
   }
 else {temp[i,1] <- 1} 
 }
```

`dput` for my `df`

```
structure(list(`10SE191_2` = c(12.6487418898415, 12.6997932097351,12.5868508174491, 12.4639169398277, 11.9846348627906, 12.8160978540904), `10SE207` = c(13.0639063105224, 12.522848114011, 12.8781769160682, 12.260865493177, 11.9664905651469, 12.7154788700468), `10SE208` = c(12.6937808736673, 12.4158248856386, 12.6602128982717, 11.7704045448312, 12.5066604109231, 12.4816357798965), mean = c(12.7393707471856, 12.5036313008127, 12.4572035036992, 12.3651842840775, 12.3313821056582, 12.3270331271091)), .Names = c("10SE191_2", "10SE207", "10SE208", "mean"), row.names = c("7995783", "8115327", "8108370", "7945680", "7923547", "8016718"), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can obtain all p-values (if possible) with this command:

```
apply(df, 1, function(x) {
  y <- df$mean[df$mean < x[4]] 
  if(length(y) > 1)
    t.test(x[1:3], y)$p.value
  else NA
})
```

The function will return `NA` if there are not enough values for `y`.

```
   7995783    8115327    8108370    7945680    7923547    8016718 
0.08199794 0.15627947 0.04993244 0.50885253         NA         NA
```

Comment: Thanks @Sven Hohenstein

Answer (score 1):

Running 2E4 `t.test`s probably takes a lot of time no matter what. Try using `Rprof` to find the hot spots.  You might also want to use `mcapply` or similar parallel processing tools, since your analysis of each row is independent of all other data (which means this is a task well-suited to multicore parallel processing).